# How to Save as a PDF file from Byte stream in iOS

Tags: ios, sharepoint, bytestream

When i used Sharepoint(getItem) Web Service for getting PDF file i got the response as Byte Stream,

I am trying to convert these Byte Stream as PDF file using below code,

```
        NSMutableData *saveData = [NSMutableData data];
        NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:byteStreamStr options:0];
            [saveData appendBytes:[decodedData bytes] length:decodedData.length];

        NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentDirectory=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *writeableDBPath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.pdf"];
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:writeableDBPath  contents:saveData attributes:nil];
```

The PDF file saved as same size of original one.But i can't open that PDF file.

Comment: Have you tried to copy that saved PDF file from device to your computer and open it?

Comment: Yes ,i tried but its show damaged file.But i can download from safari.                                                          While webservice calling I got bytes value for that pdf file.

Comment: Am I right you call WebService in browser and it returns file? If yes, then why you decode from base64?

Comment: yes i  used base64,please find the below code which i am using,                                    NSMutableData *saveData = [NSMutableData data];
            NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:bytesStr options:0];
            [saveData appendBytes:[decodedData bytes] length:decodedData.length];
Please help me ,

Comment: Are you sure WebService returns item encoded with base64? have you tried to save byte stream directly to file without base64 decoding?